# drop listbox items into grid

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, listbox

I have a listbox and a grid (5 row,1 column), may be each grid row has a canvas. When I drag an item from the listbox and drag into a row in the grid, this row will change color. How can I do it? If I want to change this row and the next row at the same time, is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Its better to show your effort what you try and where you got a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these articles -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17266/Drag-and-Drop-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22855/ListBox-Drag-Drop-using-Attached-Properties

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/12/drag-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end.aspx